# UICollectionView viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind didSelect

Tags: swift, uikit

How is a selection within a `viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind` recognized? I've tried adding a target to the button within the `header` but that doesnt work. Is the selection action sent to `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` or is there something else? All elements which header are within a `UIStackView`

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {

    if kind == UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind(UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "header", forIndexPath: indexPath) as!  mainCell
        let index = indexPath.section
        cell.btnImg.af_setBackgroundImageForState(.Normal, URL: NSURL(string: "urrl")!)
        cell.userImg.addTarget(self, action: #selector(MainController.showNextView(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        let tap = UIGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.test))
        cell.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
        return cell
    } else {

        return UICollectionReusableView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that you need to use a `UIControl` or `UIGestureRecognizer`. It looks like you are adding both in your example code and the `UIGestureRecognizer` is consuming the touches instead of your button.